# Android: Shared Element Transition with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I'm working on a project where I need a transition between fragments using shared elements. I've tried nearly everything but the transition effect isn't working.

I have an activity called TimelineActivity and I have 2 fragments, a ListFragment that is dynamically added to the TimelineActivity, and a DetailFragment.

Whenever I click on an item in the ListView in the ListFragment, the fragment is being replaced by the DetailFragment.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    DetailFragment fragment = DetailFragment.newInstance();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(2000));
        fragment.setEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(2000));
        setExitTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(2000));
        fragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(new ChangeBounds().setDuration(2000));
    }

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragment.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
    fragment.setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(true);

    ft.replace(R.id.timeline_container, fragment);
    ft.addSharedElement(view.findViewById(R.id.transition), "selectClientTransition");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);

    // Start the animated transition.
    ft.commit();
}
```

In my listview_row.xml which is the layout for the listview I have:

```
   <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/transition"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#FFF"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="10dp"
   android:transitionName="selectClientTransition">
   </LinearLayout>
```

and in my fragment_detail.xml I have the following:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/transition"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:transitionName="selectClientTransition"
                android:weightSum="12">
</LinearLayout>
```

I added this to my AppTheme

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
```

Just to be clear, the fragments are replaced, that's working fine, but without a changebounds effect. I'm really stuck here so anything is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set unique transition name for each element in the list. Here's an example:

in adapter's getView method set transition name:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // your code...

    sharedView.setTransitionName("transition_name_" + position);
}
```

in onItemClick method send transition name to DetailFragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    DetailFragment fragment = DetailFragment.newInstance();
    View sharedView = v.findViewById(R.id.shared_view);

    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(DetailFragment.TRANSITION_NAME, sharedView.getTransitionName());
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    // the rest of your code (replacing fragments, etc)...
}
```

in DetailFragment's onCreateView method set transition name to view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // your code...

    View sharedView = inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.shared_view);
    sharedView.setTransitionName(getArguments().getString(TRANSITION_NAME))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it only happens when I use a custom arrayadapter with more then 1 element in it, if I switch to a normal String array for my ListView, everything works fine, same if I have just 1 element in my listview with a custom arrayadapter, everything works fine.